# Web Api from React component returns the json in string format

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I have the following React code where I make a call to ASP.NET Web Api controller to fetch some data. The problem is that `response.data` returns the array json data as string (e.g., `"[{\"id\":7,\"......`). I am using the identical approach for many other Web Api calls and they are working fine. This one just works unexpectedly different. Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
export function FetchOverallParticipation(reviewRoundId) {

    var url = 'api/A/B';

    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(fetchOverallParticipationBegin());

        axios.get(url, { params: { reviewRoundId } })
            .then(response => {

                const participationAnalytics = new schema.Entity("participationAnalytics");
                const normalizedData = normalize(response.data, [participationAnalytics]);

                dispatch(fetchOverallParticipationSuccess(normalizedData));

            })
            .catch(error => { fetchOverallParticipationFailure(error) });
    }
}
```

Below is the Web Api method.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/A/B")]
public IEnumerable<OverallParticipationDTO> FetchOverallParticipation(int reviewRoundId)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<OverallParticipationDTO> result =
            _context.Submissions
                    .Where(s => s.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId)
                    .Select(s => new OverallParticipationDTO
                        {
                            Id = s.Id,
                            GoogleDriveDialogueFileId = s.GoogleDriveDialogueFileId,
                            GoogleDriveReadFileId = s.GoogleDriveReadFileId,
                            GoogleDriveReviseFileId = s.GoogleDriveReviseFileId,
                            ReviewedStudents = s.StudentGroup.GroupMemberships
                                               .Select(gm => gm.User)
                                               .Select(u => new ApplicationUserDto
                                               {
                                                   Id = u.Id,
                                                   FullName = u.FullName
                                               }),
                            ReviewingStudents = s.StudentGroup.AsServingReviewer.SelectMany(asr => asr.GroupReviewing.GroupMemberships)
                                               .Select(gm => gm.User)
                                               .Select(u => new ApplicationUserDto
                                               {
                                                   Id = u.Id,
                                                   FullName = u.FullName
                                               })
                        });

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are these 2 lines of code doing? `               const participationAnalytics = new schema.Entity("participationAnalytics");
                const normalizedData = normalize(response.data, [participationAnalytics]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was associated with the error inside the linq query. `OfType()` was not working for the conversion. I was supposed to use `is` to filter by the derived class:

```
   LearningActionDiscussions = s.GeneralComments
                            .Where(c=> c is LearningActionComment)
                            .OfType<LearningActionComment>()
                            .GroupBy(c => c.UserId)
                            .Select(fc => new ApplicationUserDto
                            {
                                Id = fc.Key,
                                FullName = fc.Select(a => a.User.FullName).ElementAt(0),
                                Count = fc.Count()
                            })
```

I hope it helps someone.